# How can I solve this error [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.inspect']

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I launch my Django project in a local server, It doesn't work with the errors.

It seems finally has an ImportError of the Django, but first I want to solve the error brow.

because, I checked if installed Django, added the exact path and activate the virtual environment.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.inspect'
```

in this case, how should I do?

Would you mind telling me how should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

**detailed error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/harvest_timer/manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core import checks
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import django.core.checks.caches  # NOQA isort:skip
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/caches.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.core import signals
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.dispatch import Signal
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.dispatch.dispatcher import Signal, receiver  # NOQA
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.utils.inspect import func_accepts_kwargs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.inspect'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

**dispatcher.py**

```
import threading
import weakref

from django.utils.inspect import func_accepts_kwargs


def _make_id(target):
    if hasattr(target, '__func__'):
        return (id(target.__self__), id(target.__func__))
    return id(target)


NONE_ID = _make_id(None)

# A marker for caching
NO_RECEIVERS = object()


class Signal:
    """
    Base class for all signals

    Internal attributes:

        receivers
            { receiverkey (id) : weakref(receiver) }
    """
    def __init__(self, providing_args=None, use_caching=False):
        """
        Create a new signal.

        providing_args
            A list of the arguments this signal can pass along in a send() call.
        """
        self.receivers = []
        if providing_args is None:
            providing_args = []
        self.providing_args = set(providing_args)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.use_caching = use_caching
        # For convenience we create empty caches even if they are not used.
        # A note about caching: if use_caching is defined, then for each
        # distinct sender we cache the receivers that sender has in
        # 'sender_receivers_cache'. The cache is cleaned when .connect() or
        # .disconnect() is called and populated on send().
        self.sender_receivers_cache = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary() if use_caching else {}
        self._dead_receivers = False

    def connect(self, receiver, sender=None, weak=True, dispatch_uid=None):
        """
        Connect receiver to sender for signal.

        Arguments:

            receiver
                A function or an instance method which is to receive signals.
                Receivers must be hashable objects.

                If weak is True, then receiver must be weak referenceable.

                Receivers must be able to accept keyword arguments.

                If a receiver is connected with a dispatch_uid argument, it
                will not be added if another receiver was already connected
                with that dispatch_uid.

            sender
                The sender to which the receiver should respond. Must either be
                a Python object, or None to receive events from any sender.

            weak
                Whether to use weak references to the receiver. By default, the
                module will attempt to use weak references to the receiver
                objects. If this parameter is false, then strong references will
                be used.

            dispatch_uid
                An identifier used to uniquely identify a particular instance of
                a receiver. This will usually be a string, though it may be
                anything hashable.
        """
        from django.conf import settings

        # If DEBUG is on, check that we got a good receiver
        if settings.configured and settings.DEBUG:
            assert callable(receiver), "Signal receivers must be callable."

            # Check for **kwargs
            if not func_accepts_kwargs(receiver):
                raise ValueError("Signal receivers must accept keyword arguments (**kwargs).")

        if dispatch_uid:
            lookup_key = (dispatch_uid, _make_id(sender))
        else:
            lookup_key = (_make_id(receiver), _make_id(sender))

        if weak:
            ref = weakref.ref
            receiver_object = receiver
            # Check for bound methods
            if hasattr(receiver, '__self__') and hasattr(receiver, '__func__'):
                ref = weakref.WeakMethod
                receiver_object = receiver.__self__
            receiver = ref(receiver)
            weakref.finalize(receiver_object, self._remove_receiver)

        with self.lock:
            self._clear_dead_receivers()
            if not any(r_key == lookup_key for r_key, _ in self.receivers):
                self.receivers.append((lookup_key, receiver))
            self.sender_receivers_cache.clear()

    def disconnect(self, receiver=None, sender=None, dispatch_uid=None):
        """
        Disconnect receiver from sender for signal.

        If weak references are used, disconnect need not be called. The receiver
        will be removed from dispatch automatically.

        Arguments:

            receiver
                The registered receiver to disconnect. May be none if
                dispatch_uid is specified.

            sender
                The registered sender to disconnect

            dispatch_uid
                the unique identifier of the receiver to disconnect
        """
        if dispatch_uid:
            lookup_key = (dispatch_uid, _make_id(sender))
        else:
            lookup_key = (_make_id(receiver), _make_id(sender))

        disconnected = False
        with self.lock:
            self._clear_dead_receivers()
            for index in range(len(self.receivers)):
                (r_key, _) = self.receivers[index]
                if r_key == lookup_key:
                    disconnected = True
                    del self.receivers[index]
                    break
            self.sender_receivers_cache.clear()
        return disconnected

    def has_listeners(self, sender=None):
        return bool(self._live_receivers(sender))

    def send(self, sender, **named):
        """
        Send signal from sender to all connected receivers.

        If any receiver raises an error, the error propagates back through send,
        terminating the dispatch loop. So it's possible that all receivers
        won't be called if an error is raised.

        Arguments:

            sender
                The sender of the signal. Either a specific object or None.

            named
                Named arguments which will be passed to receivers.

        Return a list of tuple pairs [(receiver, response), ... ].
        """
        if not self.receivers or self.sender_receivers_cache.get(sender) is NO_RECEIVERS:
            return []

        return [
            (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
        ]

    def send_robust(self, sender, **named):
        """
        Send signal from sender to all connected receivers catching errors.

        Arguments:

            sender
                The sender of the signal. Can be any Python object (normally one
                registered with a connect if you actually want something to
                occur).

            named
                Named arguments which will be passed to receivers. These
                arguments must be a subset of the argument names defined in
                providing_args.

        Return a list of tuple pairs [(receiver, response), ... ].

        If any receiver raises an error (specifically any subclass of
        Exception), return the error instance as the result for that receiver.
        """
        if not self.receivers or self.sender_receivers_cache.get(sender) is NO_RECEIVERS:
            return []

        # Call each receiver with whatever arguments it can accept.
        # Return a list of tuple pairs [(receiver, response), ... ].
        responses = []
        for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender):
            try:
                response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
            except Exception as err:
                responses.append((receiver, err))
            else:
                responses.append((receiver, response))
        return responses

    def _clear_dead_receivers(self):
        # Note: caller is assumed to hold self.lock.
        if self._dead_receivers:
            self._dead_receivers = False
            self.receivers = [
                r for r in self.receivers
                if not(isinstance(r[1], weakref.ReferenceType) and r[1]() is None)
            ]

    def _live_receivers(self, sender):
        """
        Filter sequence of receivers to get resolved, live receivers.

        This checks for weak references and resolves them, then returning only
        live receivers.
        """
        receivers = None
        if self.use_caching and not self._dead_receivers:
            receivers = self.sender_receivers_cache.get(sender)
            # We could end up here with NO_RECEIVERS even if we do check this case in
            # .send() prior to calling _live_receivers() due to concurrent .send() call.
            if receivers is NO_RECEIVERS:
                return []
        if receivers is None:
            with self.lock:
                self._clear_dead_receivers()
                senderkey = _make_id(sender)
                receivers = []
                for (receiverkey, r_senderkey), receiver in self.receivers:
                    if r_senderkey == NONE_ID or r_senderkey == senderkey:
                        receivers.append(receiver)
                if self.use_caching:
                    if not receivers:
                        self.sender_receivers_cache[sender] = NO_RECEIVERS
                    else:
                        # Note, we must cache the weakref versions.
                        self.sender_receivers_cache[sender] = receivers
        non_weak_receivers = []
        for receiver in receivers:
            if isinstance(receiver, weakref.ReferenceType):
                # Dereference the weak reference.
                receiver = receiver()
                if receiver is not None:
                    non_weak_receivers.append(receiver)
            else:
                non_weak_receivers.append(receiver)
        return non_weak_receivers

    def _remove_receiver(self, receiver=None):
        # Mark that the self.receivers list has dead weakrefs. If so, we will
        # clean those up in connect, disconnect and _live_receivers while
        # holding self.lock. Note that doing the cleanup here isn't a good
        # idea, _remove_receiver() will be called as side effect of garbage
        # collection, and so the call can happen while we are already holding
        # self.lock.
        self._dead_receivers = True


def receiver(signal, **kwargs):
    """
    A decorator for connecting receivers to signals. Used by passing in the
    signal (or list of signals) and keyword arguments to connect::

        @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
        def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...

        @receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=MyModel)
        def signals_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            ...
    """
    def _decorator(func):
        if isinstance(signal, (list, tuple)):
            for s in signal:
                s.connect(func, **kwargs)
        else:
            signal.connect(func, **kwargs)
        return func
    return _decorator
```

**error code after I add inspect.py myself**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 16, in setup
    from django.urls import set_script_prefix
ImportError: cannot import name 'set_script_prefix' from 'django.urls' (unknown location)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/project/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute
    _parser = self.fetch_command('runserver').create_parser('django', 'runserver')
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/harvest_timer_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import (
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import LimitedStream
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers import base
  File "/Users/apple/GoogleDrive/project_django/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.urls import get_resolver, set_urlconf
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_resolver' from 'django.urls' (unknown location)
```

**Development environment**

- Mac: mojave 10.14.6
- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 2.2.2
- Pycharm: 2019.3.1 (community edition)

Comment: Can you please show your code, where error occurs?? Also, why did you import that module??

Comment: Thank you! I added a code of dispatcher.py in my question, is it the information you need?

Comment: Absolutely.. I don't think that there is any module named inspect in django.utils . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/

Comment: I don't know why I imported that module, I mean I just thought the Django framework does that automatically.

Comment: Why don't you remove that import section, and check it...???????

Comment: Hm, strange. There is a `django/utils/inspect.py` file in Django 2.2.2: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.2/django/utils/inspect.py . It should import just fine, especially since the stacktrace shows other loaded Django modules.

Comment: Could you try uninstalling and reinstalling django?

Comment: @Boldewyn: I added inspect.py my self and then the error code changed as totally different, I added that error code in my question, so could you please check it?

Comment: @ Biplove Lamichhane : I tried your advice, then the error code is the same ad the one I added in my question as error code after I add inspect.py myself

Comment: @ Iain Shelvington: I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling django, and then I received many errors from other packages I installed.

Comment: should I add some file my self every time when I have errors following that direction of that errors?